# how to show locations in a Google map

Tags: c#

I have a database and every person has a location.
In this point, l need some sugesstions to show all the person's location in a single map.

To give an example,
X man = at y, X1 man = at z,X2 man = at q

y,z,q  will be shown in a singe map?

Comment: Metro? WinForms? WPF? Silverlight? ASP.Net? MonoTouch?

Answer (score 1):

i think it will helps you

The Google Maps API is accessed via JavaScript (any server controls are just abstracting this away from you). In the case you described, you would need to dynamically output the required JavaScript to tell the maps API what to display.

See http://dotnet.sys-con.com/node/171162

Comment: Link is dead...